# How do I play local user-provided audio files on an Android or iOS device?

Tags: unity, android, ios

I'd like to allow a user to select a path to local audio files, in Android and iOS devices. Is there a way I could provide a list of available songs, in Android or iOS devices, so the user could pick and play them?

Comment: Have you tried anything, yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be an issue due to security considerations on the devices. You can certainly try using System.IO.Directory and System.IO.File to look around, but you'll need to adjust the 'root' paths for the different devices. IOS and Android don't share the same directory structure, and I very much doubt iOS will let you look around much at all.

You could try using the **www** class to load a *file:* (local file) URL - such as *file:/storage/media/musictrack.mp3*. I've known that technique to work in Windows, and according to the post below it can also work on Android. Again, iOS may be an issue - how do you copy an MP3 file to an iOS device without iTunes?

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/334907/how-to-www-a-file-on-android.html

Comment: Thanks Steve. let me have a look at www class. would let you know how it goes.